# Saving resize width of RadSplitter with RadPanes

Tags: session, telerik

I have a RadSplitter with two RadPanes.  When I resize the control, I'd like my program to remember the position of the split so that when the user returns to the page, it will keep the position.  The only way I can think of doing it is by storing the width in a session variable that can be retrieved when the page loads.  My issue is that I can't run server-side code when the splitter is resized or when the page is closed (or the user moves to another page on the site)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [OnClientResized](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/splitter-client-side-onclientresized.html) event of the RadSplitter to store a cookie on the user's machine via JavaScript? You can retrieve it in the [OnClientLoaded](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/splitter-client-side-onclientloaded.html) event and resize the Splitter according to the values from the cookie.

On working with cookies I can recommend that you start by examining
[PPK's quirksmode.org article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) and
[w3schools' tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp) on the matter.